# I am trying to install requirements.txt for my project but it returns the error given below?

Tags: python, requirements.txt

Trying to install these packages but the same thing comes up every time.
What should I do ?

```
tensorflow==2.4.1
nltk==3.5
keras==2.4.3
numpy==1.19.5
streamlit==0.52.1
seaborn==0.11.1
tweepy==3.10.0
textblob==0.15.3
flask==1.1.2
pandas==1.2.2
matplotlib==3.2
scikit_learn==0.24.1
statsmodels==0.12.2
yfinance==0.1.54
alpha_vantage==2.3.1
https://pypi.anaconda.org/berber/simple/tweet-preprocessor/0.5.0/tweet-preprocessor-0.5.0.tar.gz
```

[Output that i have been getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhIK0.png)

Comment: What command did you use to in pip install

Comment: Are you sure that your requirements.txt is in the specified directory? Can you tell us what `Get-ChildItem` outputs?

Answer (score 0):

It says that requirements.txt does not exist in the current working directory. Is the file in the directory \Stock-Market..?

Another thing that I noticed is that you don't have a virtual environment activated. But I don't know if you want to install it specifically in a venv.

Comment: can i manually install all requirements.txt packages ?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm understandin. They're multiple requirements.txt packages? The command you need to run is the one you were running. That is, pip install -r PATH_TO_REQUIREMENTS.TXT. The error signals that you probably didn't inserted the path correctly.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).